# VS 2013 SDK: How to keybind hotkey only for Code Window Editor?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

In **C#** or else **VB.Net**, using a Visual Studio **Package**, I would like to assign a custom keyboard shortcut to a `CommandBarButton`, for example **Ctrl + E + R**, then, when pressed, the associated `CommandBarButton` should call its `Execute` method (I imagine that).

How I could do it?.

---

### Update

( please avoid question above, that issue was already answered. )

Actually I'm using an **vsct** file, then my keybinding is this:

```
<KeyBindings>

  <KeyBinding guid="guidMainCmdSet" id="cmdidMyCommand" editor="guidVSStd97" 
              mod1="Control" key1="E" 
              mod2="Control" key2="R"/>

</KeyBindings>
```

**MSDN** explains that the `guidVSStd97` is global, it seems to affect to all parts of the IDE:

**https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165973%28v=vs.90%29.aspx**

> To define key bindings at the global scope, use an Editor ID value of
>   guidVSStd97.

My extension works with the selected text of the Code Window, so its weird that for example in the solution explorer, or with any project loaded I'm able to press the hotkey.

Then, I would like to be able to press that hotkey (Ctrl+ E + R) only in the **Code Window Editor**.

My question is:

Which is the editor id of the **Code Window Editor**?

Additional requisite:

I need an **MSDN** reference to see more related editor ids, I can't find anything about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visual Studio, keyboard shortcuts are associated to commands, not directly to CommandBarButtons. Technically they are called Keyboard Bindings and are declared in the .vsct file where you declare commands. See [KeyBindings element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165085.aspx)

Edited: You have to use:

```
  <KeyBinding guid="guidVSMyPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidMyCommand" editor="guidSourceCodeTextEditor" mod1="Control" key1="X" mod2="Control" key2="X"/>
```

```
  <GuidSymbol name ="guidVisualBasicEditor" value="{2c015c70-c72c-11d0-88c3-00a0c9110049}" />

  <GuidSymbol name ="guidSourceCodeTextWithEncodingEditor" value="{c7747503-0e24-4fbe-be4b-94180c3947d7}" />

  <GuidSymbol name ="guidSourceCodeTextEditor" value="{8b382828-6202-11d1-8870-0000f87579d2}" />
```

...

where guidSourceCodeTextEditor can be any name that you define in the <Symbols> section whose value you must get from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0Exp_Config\Editors. Once you run the package, if you go to Tools >Options window, Environment > Keyboard section, type the name of your command in Show Commands Containing, and you should see the shortcut in the list with the editor between parenthesis, as if you have selected it from the "Use new shortcut in" list. Which yields us to the question if the guids are the same for each Visual Studio version. AFAIK, this is not guaranteed (nothing prevents Microsoft changing guids in a new version) but likely they are the same. I cannot verify right now because the computer that I am using only has VS 2013.

Comment: Thanks again, but again I have the same problem with this, the lack of an .vsct file because I'm using an empty vspackage where I add buttons to the code editor contextmenu and nothing more (I don't want to add any command under the "Tools" menu). really I should start my project from zero using a command menu template?.

Comment: We will continue the discussion in your "VS 2013 SDK: How to add a line separator in a CommandBarPopup menu?" thread

Comment: thanks for your experience, I've updated this question, pelase if yu could help with this.

Comment: The Editor ID, despite its name, is a Guid. The guidVSStd97 value is defined in vsshlids.h as #define guidVSStd97              CMDSETID_StandardCommandSet97 and in turn #define CMDSETID_StandardCommandSet97  { 0x5efc7975, 0x14bc, 0x11cf, { 0x9b, 0x2b, 0x00, 0xaa, 0x00, 0x57, 0x38, 0x19 } }. So, if you want a specific editor, you must know its guid and MSDN says "The value of Editor ID is a GUID that corresponds to a CmdUIGUID that was assigned by the developer when the editor is created. This Editor ID GUID value may or may not be the same as the GUID for the EditorFactory for the editor."

Comment: I don't think editor guids are documented in MSDN but they are registered in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0Exp_Config\Editors

Comment: I have not tested but try {8B382828-6202-11d1-8870-0000F87579D2} (Source Code (Text) Editor) or {C7747503-0E24-4FBE-BE4B-94180C3947D7} (Source Code (Text) Editor with Encoding)

Comment: Although https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138531.aspx says that you need the editor name (something like "guid<EditorName>EditorFactory"), not the editor guid, and that's quite difficult to get without the .vsct file of the custom editor.

Comment: Awesome how much things you know about that. I'm not sure which editor is what I want because lack of documentation, but seeying the registry key you mentioned I think could be this key with default value contains `Source Code (Text) Editor` as yours but in my side its package value contains `{e269b994-ef71-4ce0-8bcd-581c217372e8}` if our guids are different this means it could derive in a compatibility issue in other PCs? or maybe not because you said its necessary to use the name, not the guid.

Comment: `that's quite difficult to get without the .vsct file of the custom editor.` this means I can't do anything?

Comment: Try posting in the MSDN Visual Studio Integrate forum (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=vsx), Microsoft engineers of the VS team visit it and can provide an answer

Answer (score 3):

I was unable to find the relevant information for Visual Studio 2019 "C# Editor". But it relatively easy, though, not intuitive. To get the guids for the standard editors you can:

1. Go to `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard`
2. Select any command in the list
3. Open `Use new shortcut in` dropdown, select required editor
4. Assign any shortcut to it
5. Save the options
6. Go to `Tools > Import and Export Settings... > Export`
7. Unselect ALL and then choose `Environment > Keyboard`
8. Press Export and choose where to save it as `.vssettings` file
9. Open the `.vssettings` file with any text editor
10. Search for `UserShortcuts`. You'll find your modified command there
11. In the `Shortcut` node, you'll find your scope (in my case `Scope="C# Editor"`)
12. Search for that scope value (e.g. `C# Editor`)

You'll find a `Scope` XML node. In my case it is:

```
<Scope Name="C# Editor" ID="{A6C744A8-0E4A-4FC6-886A-064283054674}"/>
```

Copy the id including curly braces, and set it to the value of `<GuidSymbol ... />` as described in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31339140/2900278) in this topic. In my case it is:

```
 <GuidSymbol name="guidCSharpEditor" value="{A6C744A8-0E4A-4FC6-886A-064283054674}" />
```

Comment: Example: [Editor Guids for VS2019 Community Edition](https://gist.github.com/psxvoid/22699b898b2c0cc5b7d5135ccee53298)