# C# VSIX - "editor" attribute of KeyBindings Element

Tags: c#, key-bindings, vsix

So the .vsct file allows developer to define commands, toolBars etc. for a visual studio shell based application extension (Management Studio 2016 addin in my case).
It also alows to set key bindings for these commands, like this:

```
 <KeyBinding guid="guidMenuAndCommandsCmdSet" id="cmdidMyCommand" editor="guidVSStd97" key1="1" mod1="Control" />
```

Problem is choosing where to use the shortcut.

> guidVSStd97

is ID for global shortcut. What i want to do is binding it as a Text Editor shortcut.
Does anyone knows where to find other values for that ("editor") attribute?

Unfortunetly nothing about that in MS [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138531.aspx).

Comment: have You found the answer on this by any chance?

Comment: @Tatranskymedved what about this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31339140/6996876)?

Comment: @user1892538 I started reading this just a moment ago! Thanks mate

Comment: @user1892538 thx for this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the main details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337319/vs-2013-sdk-how-to-keybind-hotkey-only-for-code-window-editor/31339140#31339140).

All the information about editors (scopes) are stored in Registry of Visual Studio. Can be obtained on:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0Exp_Config\Editors`, where `12.0Exp_Config` can be exchganed with any other version.

After that You have to link the `GUID` in symbols as:

```
<Symbols>
    <GuidSymbol name="guidMyWindow" value="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
<Symbols>
```

Where the `0`'s should be replaced with valid `GUID` of the scope from Registry.

`KeyBinding` will look like:

```
<KeyBindings>
    <KeyBinding guid="guidMyPackageCmdSet"
                id="MyCmdId"
                editor="guidMyWindow"
                key1="S" mod1="Control" />
</KeyBindings>
```

If You are creating Your own `Keybindings`, You might want to change the scope to Your own. I would recommend going through my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42899788/7167572) on similar topic and [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/25db522a-3e81-4846-bd7b-c515c6da4219/keybinding-for-toolwindow?forum=vsx) on MSDN web.

Comment: Thx for answer.