# VSIX window - key shortcut to execute ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, vsix, envdte

Having a Visual Studio extension (VSIX) project: In `Window` we got `UserControl`, which have `Button` binded to some `ICommand`. This works perfectly as expected, however I would like to attach a key shortcut (e.g.:<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) which would fire the same `Command`.

I have checked several questions, in which I found the most useful this code:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="Esc" Command="{Binding SaveCmd}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

However the `Command` is never fired from the key-press, I think the issue(s) might be:

- code above should not be working? (I found article where the bind should be done to the `Command` with `DependencyProperty`)
- The key-press is caught by Visual Studio itself (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> is saving the file)
- I might need to set the binding on the `Window` which encapsulates the `UserControl`
- I might need to set the binding in the `*Package.vsct` and route it through as it would be a `Command` in Visual Studio

**Question(s):** How am I suppose to bind to the shortcut key-press? Where am I suppose to place the binding?

Comment: Yes, an InputBinding is the best method in my opinion. I would try your third approach first. The keys will only be captured when the Control they are defined has focus. So if you want an InputBinding for your whole application you have to define it for the window.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom And what about the Visual Studio? In my opinion the VS is higher in the stack and will `handle` the call sooner than it gets to my `Window`.

Comment: Have you tried it and it isn't working? Because I guess it should work because the command will be handled from the application with the focus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`KeyBindings` seems complicated and needs to be definied on several steps (also depends on requirements). This answer is written as a bonus to answer of [user1892538](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42885910/7167572).

**Scenario:** We got toolWindow which is already showing, but we want to add some command, which will invoke method in the view/view-model.

---

**1. Create new `Command` (*Step 3* in [this](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-your-first-visual-studio-vsix-package) tutorial):**

Right-click to the project -> Add `New Item` -> `Custom command`. This will create 2 files and modify file with package:

- **`CommandName.png`** - *icon for the menu*
- **`CommandName.cs`** - *class file including the source code of command*
- **`ProjectWindowPackage.cs`** - *Package class with `Initialize()` method, which invokes `Initialize()` of **`CommandName.cs`***

**`MyWindowPackage.cs`**:

```
public sealed class MyWindowPackage : Package
{
    public const string PackageGuidString = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003";

    public MyWindowPackage() { }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        MyToolWindowCommand.Initialize(this);
        MySaveCommand.Initialize(this);
        base.Initialize();
    }
}
```

**`CommandName.cs`**:

```
// these 2 values will do the binding
public static readonly Guid ApplicationCommands
                                  = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002");
public const int SaveCommandId = 0x0201;

private readonly Package package;

private CommandName(Package package)
{
    // we need to have package (from Initialize() method) to set VS
    if (package == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("package");
    this.package = package;

    // this provides access for the Menu (so we can add our Command during init)
    OleMenuCommandService commandService = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
    if (commandService != null)
    {
        // Creates new command "reference" (global ID)
        var menuCommandID = new CommandID(ApplicationCommands, SaveCommandId);
        // Create new command instance (method to invoke, ID of command)
        var menuItem = new MenuCommand(this.Save, menuCommandID);
        // Adding new command to the menu
        commandService.AddCommand(menuItem);
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        // Get instance of our window object (param false -> won't create new window)
        ToolWindowPane lToolWindow = this.package.FindToolWindow(typeof(MyToolWindow), 0, false);
        if ((null == lToolWindow) || (null == lToolWindow.Frame)) return;

        // Handle the toolWindow's content as Window (our control)
        ((lToolWindow as MyToolWindow)?.Content as MyWindowControl)?.Save();
    }
}
```

---

**2. Set content of MyToolWindow to MyWindowControl (done when VSIX created):**

**`MyToolWindow.cs`**:

```
[Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001")] //GUID of ToolWindow
public class MyToolWindow : ToolWindowPane
{
    public MyToolWindow() : base(null)
    {
        this.Content = new MyWindowControl();
    }
}
```

---

**3. Set code in code-behind to invoke ViewModel (or do the job itself):**

**`MyWindowControl.cs`**:

```
public partial class MyWindowControl : UserControl
{
    // output omitted for brevity

    public void Save()
    {
        // Do the call towards view-model or run the code

        (this.DataContext as MyViewModel)?.SaveCmd.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

---

**4. Set `Command` with `Shortcut` so VS know how to handle them:**

In [MZTools' article](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2014/MZ2014019.aspx) can be found solution how to add `Command` without seeing it in menu, but if You will go to Tools->Window->Keyboard, You might find them there (so You can set up shortcut).

I will show both origin `Button` (for displaying tool window) and 2nd invisible `Button` used for the shortcut (`Keybind`) only.

**`MyWindowPackage.vsct`** (in several parts):

```
<!-- shows the definition of commands/buttons in menu, Canonical name is how You can find the command in VS [Tools -> Keyboard -> CommandName] -->
<Commands package="guidMyWindowPackage">

    <Button guid="guidMyWindowPackageCmdSet"
            id="MyWindowCommandId"
            priority="0x0100"
            type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_WNDO_OTRWNDWS1" />
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>My ToolWindow</ButtonText>
      <CommandName>MyCommand</CommandName>
      <MenuText>My ToolWindow</MenuText>
      <LocCanonicalName>MyToolWindow</LocCanonicalName>
    </Strings>
  </Button>

  <Button guid="guidMyWindowPackageCmdSet"
          id="MySaveCommandId"
          priority="0x0100"
          type="Button">
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>My ToolWindow Save</ButtonText>
      <LocCanonicalName>MyToolWindow.Save</LocCanonicalName>
    </Strings>
  </Button>
</Buttons>
</Commands>
```

KeyBindings (shortcut definition):

```
<KeyBindings>
    <KeyBinding guid="guidMyWindowPackageCmdSet"
                id="MySaveCommandId"
                editor="guidVSStd97"
                key1="1" mod1="Control" />
</KeyBindings>
```

And the `Symbols`, which set and bind `GUID`, `Command definition` and `Command logic` together:

```
<Symbols>
    <!-- This is the package guid. -->
    <GuidSymbol name="guidMyWindowPackage" value="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003}" />

    <!-- This is the guid used to group the menu commands together -->
    <GuidSymbol name="guidMyWindowPackageCmdSet" value="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002}">
        <IDSymbol name="MyWindowCommandId" value="0x0100" />
        <IDSymbol name="MySaveCommandId" value="0x0201" />
    </GuidSymbol>

<!-- some more GuidSymbols -->

</Symbols>
```

**Bonus:**

`KeyBinding` does have property `editor="guidVSStd97"`, this will set the scope of binding to "GENERAL" (useable in each window). If You can set this to the `GUID` of Your `ToolWindow`, it will be used only when the `ToolWindow` is selected. How it works, is described [behind this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337319/vs-2013-sdk-how-to-keybind-hotkey-only-for-code-window-editor). And to acomplish it full, get to [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/25db522a-3e81-4846-bd7b-c515c6da4219/keybinding-for-toolwindow?forum=vsx).

Comment: Very detailed! What about [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491775.aspx) example with `editor="guidWidgetEditor"`? Look also at the example from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31339140/6996876) `editor="guidSourceCodeTextEditor"` ...

Comment: This works well, however. Is there anyway to get this commands visible under Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard?

Comment: The name that is specified in the file `MyWindowPackage.vsct` (LocCanonicalName) should be available for you in the Options menu. Check the part **Key Bindings** in the answer, this is what creates the key binding for you (and you can find in the options table).

Answer (score 3):

You're right, the shortcut is used by a default Visual Studio command which *takes precedence* over the extension.

From a similar [msdn post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/fdeec0a4-ba4e-4896-9bed-93865d65e312/shortcut-in-vsix-extension-for-vs2015-does-not-work?forum=vsx), this behavior is *confirmed* and the suggestion is to choose a *different* combination.

Find a [reference](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/) for the complete list of VS shortcuts. Shortcut keys apply at various scopes (for example, when you are in a text editor, the Text Editor scoped shortcuts take precedence over the Global shortcuts).
Aside from that, you can [customize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx) the shortcut's behavior and also import a new keyboard mapping scheme and select it under *Tools* > *Options* > *Environment* > *Keyboard*.

The `KeyBindings` section in .vsct is where you can associate a command with a keyboard shortcut. Microsoft sample is on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/blob/646de671c1a65ca49e9fce397baefe217e9123e8/Menu_And_Commands/C%23/PkgCmd.vsct)

Comment: Thank You very much for the answer, I will award You with the bounty, however I decided to answer the question myself as I believe got some more to explain. Cheers =)

Answer (score 0):

Good answer from user1892538

Also, beware that some shortcuts are taken by the operating system or by other software running on the machine.

Ctrl+Esc will activate the start menu on Windows machines.

Other examples:
- Intel graphics software takes over Ctrl+Alt+F8.
- Some Ctrl+Alt combinations can have trouble getting through remote desktop connections.